# Rewrite rule is catching pages not posts

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to implement a wordpress site where there possibly is a name generated in the format firstname.lastname at the front of the url.

I have the following rule

```
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $newrules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    $newrules = array('('.$var['RealName'].')/(.+)$' => 'index.php?pagename='.$name.'&brokername='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1));     
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $newrules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
```

I am looping and adding rules for each individual.

My problem is this works fine for Pages but does not work for Posts?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `pagename` query var, so, like the name suggests, you are requesting a page with the specified name and not other type of content/post. If you want the rewrite rule works for all types of post (except attachments), you can use the `p` query var passing the `post_ID` as value. [See the available `query_vars` in WP core](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars).

Comment: Thanks for you info but can you tell me how do I know the post_id. 

All I am trying to do it add a dynamic field to the front of all content on the wordpress site. 
i.e. http://wordpresssite/dynamic-field/rest-of-wordpress-url.  

I also need to catch the dynanic field so I can use it.